# Problemas en Autentificación y Rutas Laravel

Tags: laravel, autenticación, rutas

tengo algunos problemas en mis sistema. Cree mis propios middlewares y guards pero nose como usarlos correctamente, son 5: administrador, administrativo, profesor, apoderado y alumno.

Estoy en la vista de login (sin iniciar sesión) y escribo, por ejemplo, "sistema/asignaturas" igual me redirige a esa vista. Intente colocando constructor en el controlador de asignaturas pero solo me funciona cuando coloco solo un middleware y la idea es que el administrador y profesor puedan trabajar en ese CRUD. Algo similar me ocurre cuando hago un Route::Group, solo me funciona cuando coloco uno y la idea es que si nadie inicia sesion, al colocar alguna ruta deberia redireccionarme a login.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> ['auth','administrador']], function(){
//CRUD Asignatura
Route::resource('asignaturas','AsignaturasController');
Route::delete('asignaturas/{id}',['as'=>'asignaturas.destroy','uses'=>'AsignaturasController@destroy']);});
```

Al usar ese group routes, me logeo como administrador y al ir a la ruta de asignaturas me redirigue al login con un error 
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Aqui esta mis middlewares

Auth

```
use Closure; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Authenticate
{


public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (!Auth::guard('profesor')->check() && !Auth::guard('apoderado')->check() && !Auth::guard('administrativo')->check() && !Auth::guard('alumno')->check() && !Auth::guard('administrador')->check())  {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
           return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);

}}
```

Administrador

```
class EsAdministrador
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (!Auth::guard('administrador')->check()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    }

    return $next($request);
}}
```

mis middlewares estan en el Kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'profesor' => \App\Http\Middleware\EsProfesor::class,
    'apoderado' => \App\Http\Middleware\EsApoderado::class,
    'administrativo' => \App\Http\Middleware\EsAdministrativo::class,
    'alumno' => \App\Http\Middleware\EsAlumno::class,
    'administrador' => \App\Http\Middleware\EsAdministrador::class,
];
```

Como lo puedo solucionar ??

Answer (score 0):

Utilízalos directamente en los controllers, me explico, en la funcion boot de tu controlador,  ejemplo tu Controller de asignaturas solo puede acceder un usuario tipo admin y profesor pues sería algo como:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('administrador','profesor');
    }
```

Y como otro ejemplo imagínate que a show puede acceder cualquier usuario que visite la web pues pondrías

```
 public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('administrador','profesor') >except('show');
        }
```

Así puedes filtrar en los métodos quién puede acceder a cada vista

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero al colocar dos no me funciona, solo me agarra cuando coloco solo un middleware en el constructor